# Increase the duration of the session without affecting the performance

Tags: java, performance, session, jboss, seam

**We have a website in seam 2.2 on JBoss 7.1 application server.We are using session for user operations.Session time out is so short just 1.5 hours. And we want to improve this hour but performance very important for us when we increase session time, session is swelling and website is so slowing.Is there a way for Increase the duration of the session without affecting the performance?**

Comment: 1.5 hours is more than enough. This means, after 1.5 hours of no user-activity, the session will be dropped.

Comment: Yes, but i want to increase this time without affecting the performance

Comment: Oukay,... I think you have a lot of concurrent sessions which use a lot of your memory, and therefore the VM does a lot of garbage collecting, because it can't empty its old gen. Try to give it some more max heap size. But still, this might be the easiest solution, but not the best. Better ways would be, beside reducing session time, reduce the information stored in the session or implement a "always logged in" and "session recovery"-feature. The less memory a application needs, the better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're website is slowing down when you increase the session timeout you are probably storing too much data in the session

You can use the SEAM debug page to see what objects are being stored in the session and try to move some down to a shorter-lived scope (Page or Request), or if the data really needs to span multiple redirects then write it off to a persistent datastore and reduce the session timeout.

If on the other hand you have a very high number of concurrent sessions then you should probably look at clustering your server and using sticky sessions to spread the load across multiple Jboss instances